# Clickable Tree UI using JAVA Swing?

Tags: java, graph, tree, swingx

Basically, I need a tree UI using Java Swing. The nodes of UI should be clickable (As it may contain URLs). After searching on the internet I found that there is various type of tree UI available in java like http://graphstream-project.org etc(basically graph). But doesn't give much functionality.

[image: Sample tree needed like this]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider javax.swing.JTree?
[Here is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) quick peek how it looks and feels.